# How to make the plot from geotiff format

Tags: plotting, import

I have a  `"GeoTIFF"` format map, and I have imported it into Mathematica, then I used the `Graphics` to plot a point on the map. But I don't know how to plot the X_axle and Y_axle?

```
tif = Import["E:\\Yan.tif", "Graphics"];
Graphics[{First@tif, PointSize[0.05], 
  Point[{400, 250}, VertexColors -> Red]}]
```

And I tried the command

```
Import["E:\\Yan.tif", {"GeoTIFF", "SpatialRange"}]
```

Comment: and I try the commangd 
Import["E:\\Yan.tif", {"GeoTIFF", "SpatialRange"}]
{{{1.19133*10^7, 3.83883*10^6}, {1.19133*10^7, 
   3.83883*10^6}, {1.19133*10^7, 3.83883*10^6}}, {{1.10181*10^7, 
   3.27395*10^6}, {1.10181*10^7, 3.27395*10^6}, {1.10181*10^7, 
   3.27395*10^6}}}

it is not longtitude and latitude,why?

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
tif = Import["untitled.tif", "Graphics"];

Graphics[{First@tif, PointSize[0.05], 
  Point[{400, 250}, VertexColors -> Red]}, Axes -> True];
```

[image]

Comment: (Sorry I didn't have a map at hand)